# Foreign Key constraint error when adding MySQL stored procedure to Entity Framework context

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to get my application to talk to a MySQL database using Entity Framework 6 Database First.

I am trying to use stored procedures for create, update and delete of each entity using Entity Framework.

For a table that has no foreign keys, this is easy. However, I get an error when trying to add a stored procedure (via right-click on entity designer surface, "Update model from database...").

The error message is:

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred
>   while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   sakila.’film_actor’, CONSTRAINT ‘fk_film_actor_actor’ FOREIGN KEY
>   (‘actor id’) REFERENCES ‘actor’ (‘actor id) ON UPDATE CASCADE).

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `p_film_actor_ins` (
    IN paractor_id smallint(5) unsigned,
    IN parfilm_id smallint(5) unsigned,
    IN parlast_update timestamp
)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO film_actor
    (
        actor_id,
        film_id,
        last_update
    )
    VALUES
    (
        paractor_id,
        parfilm_id,
        parlast_update
    );

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now, fair enough that I'd get an error like that when executing the stored procedure and my data was wrong. But all I'm trying to do here is import it into my model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that your stored procedure inserts. I had the same problem.

1. Right click database model and click update model from database.
2. Select just the stored procedure with the issue.
3. Mouse over the option "**Import selected stored procedures and functions into the entity model**" and see that it also says "Expose selected store procedures via the entity model, creating return types for them when they return more than one column. **Uncheck this if stored procedures are used to insert/update/delete entity types**".
4. Uncheck that box.
5. Finish setting up stored procedure in Visual Studio Model Browser.

At this point I realised that Entity Framework 6 does not seem to support [async stored procedures](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1760) and rewrote the code as a raw SQL query.

Comment: Good call! That solved my problem.There is a "Mystery Meat" aspect to having to hover over the checkbox to get the information you really need. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_meat_navigation